# How to block Emails sent to a Group in .To and .Cc

Tags: vba, outlook

I want a request for confirmation every time I try to send an email to a group.

I came up with the following code which works but only for sending Emails to a person:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim prompt As String
On Error Resume Next

Select Case LCase(Item.To)

Case "alias@gmail.com" ' , "alias2@domain3.com", "alias3@domain3.com"
    prompt = "You are sending this to " & Item.To & ". Are you sure you want to send the Mail?"
    If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
            
Case Else
    Item.Send
        
End Select
    
End Sub
```

I cannot change "alias@gmail.com" by the contact group I created. Is it possible to enter a group instead of an email address?

My goal is to send emails to certain groups only if they are in Bcc.

**Note**: I see that Outlook recognizes groups as the code above doesn't work if I send email to a group containing one (single) Email address *alias@gmail.com*

Comment: Case LCase("the text seen in the To box when a group is the only entry")

Comment: @Niton Great that answered my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with my own answer:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim prompt As String
Dim GROUP1 As String
Dim GROUP2 As String

GROUP1 = "GROUP of People"
GROUP2 = "personx@yahoo.com"

    If InStr(Item.To, GROUP1) > 0 Or InStr(Item.To, GROUP2) Then
        prompt = "This Email is sent to the wrong person/Groups in .To"
            MsgBox (prompt)
            Cancel = True

    End If

    If InStr(Item.CC, GROUP1) > 0 Or InStr(Item.CC, GROUP2) Then
        prompt = "This Email is sent to the wrong person/Groups in .Cc"
            MsgBox (prompt)
            Cancel = True
    End If


End Sub
```

This enables me to stop if any of the group or person I wrote on top of the code are in the recipients. But it works if they are in Bcc.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to iterate through the Recipient objects in the MailItem.Recipients collection.  Then get the Recipient.AddressEntry object from each Recipient, and look to see if AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType = olOutlookDistributionListAddressEntry.  That will tell if you if it's an Outlook Contact Group (DL).

Comment: As Eric said, you need to use AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType to decide if user has group membership or not.
you could refer to these links:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.addressentryusertype  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oladdressentryusertype